# Content is hiding behind the sidebar

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

If you look at `#about` the div and its content is hiding behind the sidebar, I tried setting the height and width with different values. I even tried `inline-block` on body but it broke everything. Flex on body wasn't even working. Even after using `75%` on content and `15%` on sections it still wasn't working. I want the content to show on the sections not hide behind the sidebar

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gantari&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Haider Ali</title>
  </head>
  <body class="bg-[#262525] m-0 ">
    <nav class="m-0 p-0 w-[250px] min-h-[100vh] bg-[#3C0949] fixed">
      <div
        class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center min-h-[100vh] gap-[15px]"
      >
        <div class="">
          <img
            class="border-[5px] rounded-full border-solid border-green-900"
            width="200"
            height="130"
            src="assets/face.png"
            alt="Haider Ali"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="link">ABOUT</div>
        <div class="link">SKILLS</div>
        <div class="link">EDUCATION</div>
        <div class="link">PROJECTS</div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="min-h-[100vh] w-[100%]">
      <section id="about" class="flex min-h-[100vh] items-center">
        <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="" class="min-h-[100vh] "></section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


body {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 2px solid limegreen !important;
}

.link {
    font-family: 'Gantari', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
```

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTryH.png)

Comment: Have you tried using [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)?

Comment: @Anonymous no I haven’t. Can you help? Where should I add it?

Comment: The code you've provided does not reproduce the problem. Nobody can help you with this much of information.

Comment: in your css try adding `#about {position: relative; z-index: 1000;}`

Comment: What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `hello` is the content in your **ABOUT PAGE**, then you can push the sidebar behind using `-z-10`.

Below is the code.

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 2px solid limegreen !important;
}

.link {
    font-family: 'Gantari', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<body class="bg-[#262525] m-0 ">
    <nav class="m-0 p-0 w-[250px] min-h-[100vh] bg-[#3C0949] fixed -z-10">
      <div
        class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center min-h-[100vh] gap-[15px]"
      >
        <div class="">
          <img
            class="border-[5px] rounded-full border-solid border-green-900"
            width="200"
            height="130"
            src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/nebula_brown.png"
            alt="Haider Ali"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="link">ABOUT</div>
        <div class="link">SKILLS</div>
        <div class="link">EDUCATION</div>
        <div class="link">PROJECTS</div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="min-h-[100vh] w-[100%]">
      <section id="about" class="flex min-h-[100vh] items-center">
        <div class="bg-purple-300">
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="" class="min-h-[100vh] "></section>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Now you can position the content so that it does not overlap with the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to the section like below will help you

```
<section id="about" class="p-[5rem]">
   <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
   </div>
</section>
```